# How to close Socket in tail-recursive?

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang, udp

I create one udp client, and need to send message every 5s, so i write

```
start() ->
  {ok, Sock} = gen_udp:open(0, []),
  send(Sock).

send(Sock) ->
  gen_udp:send(Sock, "127.0.0.1", 3211, "hello world"),
  timer:sleep(5000),
  send(Sock).
```

I want to know a good place to close the socket

Answer (score 7):

If your goal is to send a message every 5 seconds, then why would you want to close the socket? If you have some logic to determine when you have sent enough messages (you count them for example), then that would be the place to close the socket.

Here's an example of how you could count the messages in a long-running process:

```
start() ->
    {ok, Sock} = gen_udp:open(...),
    send(Sock, 0),
    gen_udp:close(Sock).

send(Sock, N) when N >= ?MAX_MESSAGE_COUNT ->
    ok;
send(Sock, N) ->
    ...
    send(Sock, N+1).
```

By counting up to a given number, instead of down, you can change this number while the process is running by simply reloading the code.

Comment: thanks!  I just want to close the socket graceful when terminating process

Comment: Your code doesn't follow good practice http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR13 you should write `start() -> ..., send(Sock), close(Sock).` and let `send` just finish.

Comment: @Hynek: You're right. Updated the code sample in my answer to reflect your input.